# We want to use Apple pay merchant id in multiple developer account?

Tags: ios, xcode, applepay, applepay-web

We have an Apple developer account for website and we had create `Apple Pay` merchant id for that website, it's already live.

Now we have developed iOS app on another Apple developer account.
Now we want to use same website merchant id for iOS app.

When we try to add website merchant id of another Apple developer account in Xcode it show following error.

"A Merchant ID with Identifier `merchant.com.example.app` is not available. Please enter a different string"

Comment: You can't use the same merchant ID on two different developer accounts.  Merchant IDs need to be globally unique